# Using isset php function to determine is a key is set in the super global Session array

Tags: php, session, authentication, isset

I have a page called login.php. Login.php processes user information. If the passed user information is found in the database a new session is started. The name and password are then added to the super global sessions array

```
if(correct_password($name, $password, $users, $users_size)) {
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
$_SESSION["password"] = $password;
header("Location: account.php");
```

After the validation the user is redirected to account.php. I want to ensure that the user is logged in i.e the "name" index is set before they can access account.php. In order to do this I have the following code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die;
}
```

This code is suppose to check to see if the "name" index is set. If it is not set it means the user is not logged in and should therefore be directed back to index.php. However it seems that even if the user logs in the if always is true. I even tested

```
echo isset($_SESSION["name"]);
die;
```

to simplify things. When this is done nothing appears on the screen meaning that isset evaluated to false. If I try to print the global sessions array in account.php it works. The data prints and it shows that the name field is populated with the data submited from login.php.

What am I misunderstanding about isset? Or did I mess up somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried all the answers below and none of them have worked for me yet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to have `session_start();` on top of the page where you *check* for that value, not only where you *set* it.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die;
}
```

Comment: Also, there really isn't a good reason to ever store a password in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

This can also work for you:

```
if( false == isset( $_SESSION ) && false == isset( $_SESSION['name'] )
    header("Location: index.php");
    die;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It allows me to access todolist.php without being logged in just like before.

Comment: If you are looking to handle authentication procedure, I will tell you one suggestion which I have seen in most of CMS. When you post data from your login form authenticate it, if the user credentials are correct instead of session create cookie which is just like as a flag "is_user_logged_in". On all other pages just check that cookie is set or not & at the time of logout just unset that cookie, beacuse storing username & password in is not a secure way. afterall everything is upto devveloper what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Storing username and password either in cookie and session is not a good idea
try this will help you out

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name']) && null != $_SESSION['name']){
    //name is exist don't forgot validate username against database
}
```

Comment: When I use this it redirects if I try access todolist.php but it also redirects if the user correctly logs in. This seems like it never allows me to get to todolist.php

Answer (score 0):

Hey to everyone who answered this question thank you. All your answers worked. The reason I thought they were not working is because I forgot to destroy the session after the user logged in. So even after log out the name index was still set.